# Is it acceptable in the workplace to ask for critique of resumes or cover letters? As long as all personal information is removed?

Tags: discussion, site-policy

I just would like to know if it is acceptable use of this site to have resumes or cover letters critiqued with of course all the personal information removed. Is that acceptable use of this site?

Comment: As jcmeloni says, resume critique really isn't a workplace problem; however, you may find some helpful information here on this post: http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/7355/to-what-extent-do-attributes-making-a-resume-good-generalize-across-industries

Comment: It's perfectly fine to ask questions in our [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3060/the-water-cooler) though, but we don't guarantee any answers :) And it would be better if you had specific questions, and didn't copy/paste your whole resume there.

Comment: It's really better to ask about resumes on a as-needed basis, and make questions applicable to more than just you. "How do I find / approach people who will give me useful advice on a resume" is a good Q, for example...

Answer (score 5):

No, that is explicitly off-topic per the [faq](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/faq):

```
"Please review my resume/CV"
Questions need to apply to more than just you. Since this site is here to help
everyone, and not review to a specific resume, these are not "questions" to
us as they don't have definite answers.
```

Comment: Just to add - the reason for this is that this site is intended in many senses to become a database of helpful Q/As related to the Workplace. Specific questions about resumes are difficult to make into questions like this. There are some questions though about resumes - you just need to make sure they would be relevant to others as well

Comment: @enderland Firstly, wow this question is old! Second, wouldn't examples of resumes (the original, the edits, and the final product) serve as an excellent database for users to base their resumes on? When I originally wrote mine, I based the formatting off of a family friend's in addition him what words I should use.

Comment: @Riorank maybe - the problem is that examples don't give guiding principles the way specific questions do. Every person and their experiences are unique and so are the cultural contexts for their resumes. Examples can be good, but lack explanations that let others more effectively craft their own.

Comment: Noted. Thanks for replying!